# Cloud Function fails with message "Error: function crashed out of request scope"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I cannot get the simplest Firebase Cloud Function to execute properly. The code below does not produce any console logging, except for the error:  `Error: function crashed out of request scope` and `Function invocation was interrupted.`

```
exports.testFunction = functions.firestore.document('trigger/dummy2').onUpdate(async (change : any, context : any) => {
    console.log( "How can this fail?" );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It was not obvious from the documentation (to me, at least), but `async` functions are required to return a Promise. If that is an irrelevant requirement, you can return a resolved promise.

```
exports.testFunction = functions.firestore.document('trigger/dummy2').onUpdate(async (change : any, context : any) => {
    console.log( "How can this fail?" );
    return Promise.resolve(100);
});
```

Comment: I would suggest you watch the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/

Comment: Yes, in this case that would have saved me time. FWIW, a simple MWE-type example is often more helpful than a video—though the videos are charming. :-)